# CloudFoundry quickstart problems. All proposed fixes don't work

Tags: single-sign-on, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

Followed this guide: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa#quick-start

First problem after doing "./gradlew run" It get's stuck at cargoRunLocal.

```
<============-> 96% EXECUTING [7m 57s]
> :cargoRunLocal
```

Then I found out that for some people changing build.gradle line like this worked. Found some variations and tried all of them with no luck.

```
-DLOGIN_CONFIG_URL=file://"+new 
File(".").absolutePath+"/uaa/src/main/resources/required_configuration.yml 

with 

-DLOGIN_CONFIG_URL=file:///"+new 
File(".").absolutePath.replace("\\","/")+"/uaa/src/main/resources/required_configuration.yml
```

Then I noticed the default branch is "develop" so I switched to "master" branch but got the same results.

Some messages from logs that might help to understand the problem.

## 1

```
INFO --- UaaMetricsEmitter: Could not find UaaMetrics object on MBean server. Please deploy UAA in the same JVM.
```

## 2

```
cloudfoundry-identity-server/uaa - 4596 [main] .... ERROR --- RecognizeFailureDispatcherServlet: Unable to start UAA application.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'activeKeyService' defined in class path resource [spring/login-ui.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'encryption.active_key_label' in value "${encryption.active_key_label}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'encryption.active_key_label' in value "${encryption.active_key_label}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.web.RecognizeFailureDispatcherServlet.init(RecognizeFailureDispatcherServlet.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'encryption.active_key_label' in value "${encryption.active_key_label}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:220)
```

## 3

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'encryption.active_key_label' in value "${encryption.active_key_label}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:220)
    ... 58 more
```

**Extra facts**: Tomcat server starts. Going to "http://localhost:8080/uaa/" says "FAILURE"

Comment: facing the same issue. did you find any solution?